# Is it possible to have similar standard errors for marginal effects under a probit regression for all estimates?

Tags: r, regression

Data: [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tj6ycmy19t0rqej/ENAE_Probit.csv?dl=0)

Code:

```
## Regression
probit_enae = glm(emploi ~ genre + filiere + satisfaction + competence + anglais, family=binomial(link="probit"),
              data=ENAE_Probit.df)
summary(probit_enae) #Summary output of the regression
confint(probit_enae) #Gives the 95% confidence interval for the estimated coefficients

## Marginal effects
mfx_enae = mfx(probit_enae)
```

So, when you run the mfx command to get the marginal effects, it works. But then you get a standard error estimate (9.901) which is the same across all estimated parameters. Is this a normal behavior?

Thanks

Comment: The link to the data is dead.